# Can "number += 1" be explained intuitively/mnemonically?

Tags: operators, conventions

**Previous research**

In several languages (perl, python, php, etc.) there is the `<value> += <increment>` operator**, which increments a `<value>` by adding `<increment>` to it. This can be used in a for loop, which will cumulatively add `<increment>` to `<value>` with each iteration. This saves having to type more explicitly (verbosely): `<value> = <value> + <increment>`.

The trouble with this operator is that one often forgets whether it was `+=` or `=+`. I often learn I have typed it the wrong way later, the hard way.

I thought I would finally learn the intuition in [this PHP tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPNmZ94FJfI&t=01m35s) ([01:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPNmZ94FJfI&t=01m35s)), but he fumbles it.

**Question**

- Is there an intuitive "in plain english" way of explaining why it is `+=` instead of `=+` or was it some convention that was arbitrarily set once upon a time?
- If "Yes" to the above, then what is this intuitive way of explaining why it is `+=`?

** Please let me know in comments what this operator is formally known as.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213184/217863

Comment: @apaul34208 thanks for the heads up, but it does seem quite paradoxical no?

Comment: Paradoxical  in what way?

Comment: @apaul34208 By removing salutations I was trying to "clean up" people's questions: an activity that so many reviewers accepted that it earned me a silver "strunk and white" badge. And now, I am being asked to stop it because I did it too rapidly last night.

Comment: Also thanks for the heads up to you too @PiotrWolkowski

Comment: There's no problem with the speed and removing thanks is a good thing to do, but while you're there take a moment to clean up other issues as well. While reviewing your edits I noticed a lot of other things that could have used some attention that you over looked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74736/discussion-between-hello-there-andy-and-apaul34208).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the non-equals sign before the equals sign reduces perceived ambiguity: `a-=b` can only mean "Decrement `a` by `b`", but `a=-b` could also mean "Set `a` to the negated value of `b`".

This wouldn't technically be ambiguous, since the C parsing rules are clear that token consumption is greedy (that is, if `=-` were an operator, the parser would always prefer to parse it as `=-` rather than `= -`), but clearly it would have been ambiguous from a readability standpoint.

Comment: This would definitely be the best way to understand it from a compiler point of view :) It definitely does remove ambiguity for statements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know history behind this one, but I've always just thought of it as

+= "add it first, assign it next". So if you're in a read left to right culture (english) then this makes sense as adding comes first, then assigning comes next.

Please see Sneftel's answer for a very good technical reason.